# No match for ess-rdired

Tags: ess, r

I'm not able to invoke the rdired-buffer when typing `M-x ess-rdired`, I get a "no match"-message. I'm also not able to find the function `ess-rdired` in the documentation (via `C-h f`).  Any idea of what's going on?

**Edit**: I'm using the Emacs bundle by [Vincent Goulet](https://vigou3.gitlab.io/emacs-modified-macos/), which is apparently your standard GNU Emacs 26.3, with additional packages such as ESS and AUCTeX. These settings are applied at start-up: 1) [site-start.el](https://gitlab.com/vigou3/emacs-modified-macos/blob/v26.3-modified-2/site-start.el), 2) followed by my .emacs-file (se below), and finally 3) [default.el](https://gitlab.com/vigou3/emacs-modified-macos/blob/v26.3-modified-2/default.el).

Initially I had the following in my .emacs-file:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)

(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd ";") 'ess-insert-assign)
(define-key inferior-ess-mode-map (kbd ";") 'ess-insert-assign)
```

But the issue of not finding `ess-rdired` persists even if I comment out everything from my .emacs-file.

I can also see that both `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/site-lisp/ess/ess-rdired.el` and its compiled version are indeed in the app-folder. But searching for the command using e.g. `C-h a` returns no match!

Comment: If you're unable to find the function `ess-rdired`, are you sure that ESS is correctly installed and loaded through your init file? Can you provide (at least the most essential lines of) the ESS-related code in your init file?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've added some additional info in my question!